# Error in winrt tile updates C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am trying to schedule several messages for update on the tile but the 4th line on the second method  `tileTextAttributes[0].InnerText = Message;` keeps throwing exceptions saying incorrect parameters. Can you help me solve the problem?

```
private void SetupTiles()
{
    try
    {
        DateTimeOffset time = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.Count; i++)
        {
            Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledTileNotification stf = new ScheduledTileNotification(GetTile(messages[i]), time);
            time.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30, 0));
            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().AddToSchedule(stf);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();
    }
}

XmlDocument  GetTile(string Message)
{
    XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideText05);
   string t = tileXml.ToString();

    XmlNodeList tileTextAttributes = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    tileTextAttributes[0].InnerText = Message;

    XmlDocument squareTileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquareText04);

    XmlNodeList squareTileTextAttributes = squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    squareTileTextAttributes[0].AppendChild(squareTileXml.CreateTextNode(Message));

    IXmlNode node = tileXml.ImportNode(squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("binding").Item(0), true);
    tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("visual").Item(0).AppendChild(node);

    return tileXml;
}
```

**Edit**

> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.
>
> at
>   Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledTileNotification..ctor(XmlDocument
>   content, DateTimeOffset deliveryTime)
>     at
>   TestProj.MainPage.SetupTiles() in c:\Users\ddds\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\TestProj\TestProj\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 398

Comment: Please post the exact error message!

Comment: Instead of the `ex.Message` log the whole exception with `Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.ToString()).ShowAsync()` and post that.

Comment: @nemesv i've edited again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML seems fine to me, but you're scheduling the notification for a moment that has just passed.  Add the time offset BEFORE the constructor.

**EDIT**
Looks like it's a bit more subtle than that, I think perhaps because how the various time functions work vis-à-vis UTC.   For example,

```
DateTimeOffset time = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
```

is ok, but not:

```
DateTimeOffset time = DateTime.Now;
time = time.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3, 0, 0));
```

I have some info in my [blog post on Scheduled Notifications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/08/windows-8-notifications-scheduled-notifications.aspx) that might help.